# Mysql cursor loop running only once

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, cursor

I'm working with mysql stored procedures and I've spent the last two hours trying to figure out why this cursor is only running once. (**I'm assuming it's only running once because I only see one record after I run this stored procedure - there's a `select * from resultado` command  at the end, where I select everything from the temporary table I've created earlier on**)

**NOTE** I've already tried running the query in the cursor on its own, and it works ok (more than one record is returned - as it should be).

I think it must be something to do with my inserting data from within the loop (I would like one row of data to be inserted into the temporary table in each loop pass).

```
-- cursors
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;

-- this query, qhen run on its own, returns more than one record
DECLARE assessments_cur CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT a.id assessment_id, 
        a.name assessment_name, 
        a.create_date data_entrada,
        a.open_date data_inicio,
        a.close_date data_fim

    FROM assessments a

    WHERE a.create_date > '2013-02-28 00:00:00'
    AND a.create_date < '2014-02-28 00:00:00'
    AND a.client_id = 13
    AND a.open_date IS NOT NULL
    AND a.close_date IS NOT NULL
;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

-- tabelas temporárias
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS resultado;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE resultado (
    nome_assessment VARCHAR(511) NOT NULL,
    segmento VARCHAR(511) NOT NULL,
    sequencia_assessment VARCHAR(511) NOT NULL,
    demanda VARCHAR(511) NULL,
    data_entrada DATETIME NOT NULL,
    data_inicio DATETIME NOT NULL,
    data_fim DATETIME NOT NULL,
    quantidade_vulnerabilidades int(11) NOT NULL,

);

OPEN assessments_cur;

REPEAT

    FETCH assessments_cur INTO 
        assessment_id_n,
        assessment_name_vr,
        data_entrada_dt,
        data_inicio_dt,
        data_fim_dt;

    SET demanda_vr = get_demanda(assessment_id_n);
    SET segmento_vr = get_segmento(assessment_id_n);

    SET quantidade_vulnerabilidades_n = get_quantidade_vulnerabilidades(assessment_id_n);

    INSERT INTO resultado(
            nome_assessment,
            segmento,
            sequencia_assessment,
            demanda,
            data_entrada,
            data_inicio,
            data_fim,
            quantidade_vulnerabilidades
        ) VALUES(
            assessment_name_vr,
            segmento_vr,
            'Foo',
            demanda_vr,
            data_entrada_dt,
            data_inicio_dt,
            data_fim_dt,
            quantidade_vulnerabilidades_n
    );


UNTIL done END REPEAT;

CLOSE assessments_cur; 

select * from resultado;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE resultado;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not have the following information:

- Table structure: `assessments`
- Functions: `get_demanda`, `get_segmento` and `get_quantidade_vulnerabilidades`

However, in a small example you can see how the cursor in action. Compare the stored procedure sample with your code and adjust as necessary.

```sql
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_test`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`()
BEGIN
-- cursors
DECLARE `done` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE `assessment_name_vr`, `segmento_vr`, `demanda_vr` VARCHAR(511);
DECLARE `data_entrada_dt`, `data_inicio_dt`, `data_fim_dt` DATETIME;
DECLARE `assessment_id_n`, `quantidade_vulnerabilidades_n` INT(11);

-- this query, qhen run on its own, returns more than one record
DECLARE `assessments_cur` CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT `a`.`id` `assessment_id`,
    `a`.`name` `assessment_name`,
    `a`.`create_date` `data_entrada`,
    `a`.`open_date` `data_inicio`,
    `a`.`close_date` `data_fim`
    FROM `assessments` `a`
    /*WHERE `a`.`create_date` > '2013-02-28 00:00:00'
    AND `a`.`create_date` < '2014-02-28 00:00:00'
    AND `a`.`client_id` = 13
    AND `a`.`open_date` IS NOT NULL
    AND `a`.`close_date` IS NOT NULL*/;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET `done` := 1;

-- tabelas temporárias
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `resultado`;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `resultado` (
    `nome_assessment` VARCHAR(511) NOT NULL,
    `segmento` VARCHAR(511) NOT NULL,
    `sequencia_assessment` VARCHAR(511) NOT NULL,
    `demanda` VARCHAR(511) NULL,
    `data_entrada` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `data_inicio` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `data_fim` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `quantidade_vulnerabilidades` INT(11) NOT NULL
);

OPEN `assessments_cur`;

REPEAT
    FETCH `assessments_cur` INTO 
        `assessment_id_n`,
        `assessment_name_vr`,
        `data_entrada_dt`,
        `data_inicio_dt`,
        `data_fim_dt`;

    IF (NOT `done`) THEN
        /*SET `demanda_vr` := `get_demanda`(`assessment_id_n`);*/
        SET `demanda_vr` := CONCAT('demanda_vr', CONVERT(`assessment_id_n`, CHAR));

        /*SET `segmento_vr` := `get_segmento`(`assessment_id_n`);*/
        SET `segmento_vr` := CONCAT('segmento_vr', CONVERT(`assessment_id_n`, CHAR));

        /*SET `quantidade_vulnerabilidades_n` := `get_quantidade_vulnerabilidades`(`assessment_id_n`);*/
        SET `quantidade_vulnerabilidades_n` := `assessment_id_n`;

        INSERT INTO `resultado` (
            `nome_assessment`,
            `segmento`,
            `sequencia_assessment`,
            `demanda`,
            `data_entrada`,
            `data_inicio`,
            `data_fim`,
            `quantidade_vulnerabilidades`
        )
        VALUES
        (
            `assessment_name_vr`,
            `segmento_vr`,
            'Foo',
            `demanda_vr`,
            `data_entrada_dt`,
            `data_inicio_dt`,
            `data_fim_dt`,
            `quantidade_vulnerabilidades_n`
        );
    END IF;
UNTIL `done` END REPEAT;

CLOSE `assessments_cur`;

SELECT * FROM `resultado`;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE `resultado`;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6893c/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

try to remove aliases from select query, like this:

```
SELECT a.id, 
    a.name, 
    a.create_date,
    a.open_date,
    a.close_date

FROM assessments a

WHERE a.create_date > '2013-02-28 00:00:00'
AND a.create_date < '2014-02-28 00:00:00'
AND a.client_id = 13
AND a.open_date IS NOT NULL
AND a.close_date IS NOT NULL
```